# Remove white space at the start of new section in latex

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vspace, layout

Using this code:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,nofootinbib,notitlepage,tightenlines]{revtex4-1}
\linespread{2}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\raggedbottom
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern -1ex\rule{0.3\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\ 
\vspace{1ex}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={small,stretch=1}}
%\usepackage[bottom,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}


\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=8em\indent}}

\begin{document}



\begin{center}\section{THEORY \& HYPOTHESES}
\label{sec:analysis}
```

to create the following new section and, as you can see, when the code is compiled the outcome includes a large vertical space. The same thing does not occur for any of my other sections despite using the exact same code pattern.

[image]

I tried using a variety of \vspace commands but could not get anything to work.

Comment: Please provide small but complete document which reproduce your problem. Instead of real text you can use dummy text from package `lipsum` or `blindtext`. Form provided fragments it is impossible to say, what went wrong with your document.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question. I am very new to latex and I did not write the original code so I am confused on how to shorten it in an appropriate manner.

Comment: @GrahamStreich you remove all the parts that don't make a difference, often doing so you discover a poor sequence / duplicate or rouge out of sync item just adding \lipsum[1]
\end{center}
\end {document} to your mwe I see No problem

Comment: I see. I do not know exactly how to do that...is there any general command for removing spacing?

Comment: if this is article for some journal, don't worry about this space. They will managed all formatting issues of article. This space is partly influenced by article content which follows this paragraph (is there some figure/table with placement option `H`?) and partly by used double spacing. For test try replace all option `[H]` with `[ht]`at your floats (`figure`/`table`) and remove `\linespread{2}` in preamble.

Comment: Also,  why do you have a `\section` command inside a `center` environment?   Do you want the section title to be centered?  Look at the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,nofootinbib,notitlepage,tightenlines]{revtex4-1}
\linespread{2}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{center}
\section{THEORY \& HYPOTHESES}
\label{sec:analysis}
\end{center}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\blindtext 

\section{THEORY \& HYPOTHESES}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

A few pointers:

1. Don't put `\section` inside a center environment.  Look at the two pages produced by the code above side by side and you'll see that doing so creates extra space.
2. Try `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.
3. Try `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.
4. If none of those work then post a complete example demonstrating your actual problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm learning a lot of Latex today.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I could get around the formatting issues by explicitly separating the sections by placing a `\newpage` after the text of the section.

Comment: Use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage` if you want the floats to stay with their section.

Comment: What are floats?

Comment: Tables and figures